# How do I detect if the 7zip file is password protected?

Tags: java, 7zip

Our project is using JAVA, the UI allows customer to upload 7-zip files with/without password, the requirement is to check if the files are password protected or not.

How can I do this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't know the details but probably you will use the 7zip Java SDK library. Then try to open without password and if fails it is probably password protected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use the sevenzipjbind, when you get the ISevenZipInArchive you can check if it has the property ENCRYPTED

Comment: Can you help me with 7zip related question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71558436/command-to-extract-password-protected-zip-file-using-p7zip?

Answer (score 1):

With sevenzipjbind it is not enough to check Archive property only. You have to check property of each item in archive.

```
boolean isEncrypted(IInArchive archive) throws SevenZipException {
    if (Boolean.TRUE.equals(archive.getArchiveProperty(PropID.ENCRYPTED))) return true;
    for (int i=0;i<archive.getNumberOfItems();i++) {
        if (Boolean.TRUE.equals(archive.getProperty(i,PropID.ENCRYPTED))) return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```