# Command to extract password protected zip file using p7zip

Tags: java, android, zip, unzip, 7zip

I'm using an open source GitHub project [AndroidP7Zip](https://github.com/hzy3774/AndroidP7zip) which is an Android wrapper over [p7zip](https://sourceforge.net/projects/p7zip/) to support zip, 7zip and other archive formats for Android project.

From android side implementation we pass the commands to the C++ code through JNI, like for extract we use following string as extract, compress command:

```
String.format("7z x '%s' '-o%s' -aoa", archivePath, outPath); // extract


String.format("7z a -t%s '%s' '%s'", type, outPath, filePath) // Compress
```

Similarly, I need to know the commands for performing below actions on file using p7zip:

1. Checking if a file is password protected?
2. Extracting a password protracted file
3. Compressing multiple files at a time
4. Compress command with password.

Tried searching but couldn't find list of all the possible commands of p7zip anywhere.

Comment: while i don't necessarily have any issues with your question, it would probably be useful to ask on the github page as well, in case you haven't yet

Comment: I have asked on GitHub also but no response! So through SO I could reach dev who might have used this library